# find match of an array value from one array column

Tags: php, mysql

hello friends i have a code. i found matching of one array value in another array column and updated row with second array value. but i want to update status of first array record in mysql table with zero when no matches found.anybody knows please help. i will provide my code below

```
foreach ($result as $rel)
{
    foreach ($array as $arr)
    {
        if(strcmp(trim($rel['objId']),trim($arr['BCEID']))==0)
        {
            $name=$arr['FirstName'];
            $conditn=$rel['objId'];

            $sql1="UPDATE e_student SET Name = '$name' WHERE objId ='$conditn'";

            $result=$conn->query($sql1);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: What is the error you have here?

Comment: no error, when no matches found for a value from first array, in database i want to update that row's status to zero

Comment: And what? What do you want from us? Help you with what?

Comment: Add the array as well allowing us to have some idea.

Comment: i want to update table field status to zero when no matches found

Comment: So write a query and execute it.

Comment: the problem is that, first array's value comparing with all  BCEID of second array.so one value comparing with 3 or more times with second array.so if i put in else case every rows status will be updated to zero,so help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($result as $rel)
{
    $clk = 'no';
    foreach ($array as $arr)
    {
        if(strcmp(trim($rel['objId']),trim($arr['BCEID']))==0)
        {
            $clk = 'yes';
            $name=$arr['FirstName'];
            $conditn=$rel['objId'];

            $sql1="UPDATE e_student SET Name = '$name' WHERE objId ='$conditn'";

            $result=$conn->query($sql1);
        }
    } 
    if($clk=='no')
    {
        // write query here to set status 0
    }
}
```